# Table has a composite primary key which is not supported by crud generator

Tags: yii

I am working with YII framework. I tried to generate a model for my DB using the YII framwwork and it made everything correctly, however when I tried to use the Crud Generator for my DB it worked for all the tables but 1 table, for that I get this error:

```
Table 'doe_logline' has a composite primary key which is not supported by crud generator.
```

here is my database in more details:

[image]

how can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately standard Yii Crud Generator doesn't support tables with composite key.

Check this [discussion](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6863-composite-primary-key-not-supported-by-crud-command).

There are two options:

1. Create all pages manually. Don't forget to extend your `doe_logline.php` with composite key definition:

   ```
   public function primaryKey(){
      return array('id', 'case_id');
   }
   ```
2. Use external tools such as [hansoncoding.net yii crud generator](http://yii.handsoncoding.net/), which can generate CRUD also for tables with composite keys.

Comment: I used your advice and add  public function primaryKey(){
   return array('id', 'case_id');
}
to my DoeLogline.php however I still get the same error. when you say create al pages manuallyw what do you mean? I have neveer used the YII framework before and its my first time.

Comment: That means you have to write `create.php, index.php, update.php` and not generate it. Otherwise try to use external tools.